# Jackson deserialization error handling

Tags: java, json, deserialization, jackson

My problem is fairly simple : I have the following simple class:

```
public class Foo {
   private int id = -1;
   public void setId(int _id){ this.id = _id; }
   public int getId(){ return this.id; }
}
```

And I am trying to process following JSON:

```
{
  "id": "blah"
}
```

Obviously, there is a problem here ("blah" cannot be parsed to an int)

Formerly, Jackson throws something like org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.lang.Integer from String value 'blah': not a valid Integer value

I agree with this, but I'd like to register something somewhere allowing to ignore this type of mapping errors.
I tried with a DeserializationProblemHandler registered (see [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToIgnoreUnknown)) but it seems to only work on unknown properties and not deserialization problems.

Have you any clue on this issue?

Comment: Why do you want to ignore this error? I'd return a HTTP code of `400` to every client who tries to `PUT` me a resource representation like this :)

Comment: I'm using Jackson with Spring MVC and bean validation.
Problem is Jackson is complaining about deserialization problems, before I reach the spring mvc layer .. so I cannot send to my client the errors in a consistent way.

Comment: Also I (for one) use Jackson quite often to do a readable dump of an object to a log.  Being able to note serialization issues and move on is very helpful

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I succeeded to solve my problem, thanks to [Tatu from Jackson ML](http://markmail.org/search/list:org.codehaus.jackson#query:%20list:org.codehaus.jackson.user+page:1+mid:toy6mh4wpezo3mnq+state:results).

I had to use custom non blocking deserializers for every primitive types handled in Jackson.
Something like this factory :

```
public class JacksonNonBlockingObjectMapperFactory {

    /**
     * Deserializer that won't block if value parsing doesn't match with target type
     * @param <T> Handled type
     */
    private static class NonBlockingDeserializer<T> extends JsonDeserializer<T> {
        private StdDeserializer<T> delegate;

        public NonBlockingDeserializer(StdDeserializer<T> _delegate){
            this.delegate = _delegate;
        }

        @Override
        public T deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            try {
                return delegate.deserialize(jp, ctxt);
            }catch (JsonMappingException e){
                // If a JSON Mapping occurs, simply returning null instead of blocking things
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    private List<StdDeserializer> jsonDeserializers = new ArrayList<StdDeserializer>();

    public ObjectMapper createObjectMapper(){
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        SimpleModule customJacksonModule = new SimpleModule("customJacksonModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
        for(StdDeserializer jsonDeserializer : jsonDeserializers){
            // Wrapping given deserializers with NonBlockingDeserializer
            customJacksonModule.addDeserializer(jsonDeserializer.getValueClass(), new NonBlockingDeserializer(jsonDeserializer));
        }

        objectMapper.registerModule(customJacksonModule);
        return objectMapper;
    }

    public JacksonNonBlockingObjectMapperFactory setJsonDeserializers(List<StdDeserializer> _jsonDeserializers){
        this.jsonDeserializers = _jsonDeserializers;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then calling it like this way (pass as deserializers only those you want to be non blocking) :

```
JacksonNonBlockingObjectMapperFactory factory = new JacksonNonBlockingObjectMapperFactory();
factory.setJsonDeserializers(Arrays.asList(new StdDeserializer[]{
    // StdDeserializer, here, comes from Jackson (org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializer)
    new StdDeserializer.ShortDeserializer(Short.class, null),
    new StdDeserializer.IntegerDeserializer(Integer.class, null),
    new StdDeserializer.CharacterDeserializer(Character.class, null),
    new StdDeserializer.LongDeserializer(Long.class, null),
    new StdDeserializer.FloatDeserializer(Float.class, null),
    new StdDeserializer.DoubleDeserializer(Double.class, null),
    new StdDeserializer.NumberDeserializer(),
    new StdDeserializer.BigDecimalDeserializer(),
    new StdDeserializer.BigIntegerDeserializer(),
    new StdDeserializer.CalendarDeserializer()
}));
ObjectMapper om = factory.createObjectMapper();
```

Answer (score 12):

You might want to let your controller handle the problem by adding a method that handles this specific exception

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
@ResponseBody
public String handleHttpMessageNotReadableException(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex)
{
    JsonMappingException jme = (JsonMappingException) ex.getCause();
    return jme.getPath().get(0).getFieldName() + " invalid";
}
```

Of course, the line

```
    JsonMappingException jme = (JsonMappingException) ex.getCause();
```

might throw a class cast exception for some cases but i haven't encountered them yet.

Comment: You're right, this could be a valid solution.


Nevertheless, it has some drawbacks :
- You will have errors reported one by one (you will need 3 requests to identify you have 3 badly formatted fields).
Putting null value when field is badly formatted allows me to put a \@NotNull annotation on the field in order to have an exhaustive list of errors in 1 request
- This allows a case-by-case handling on each fields. If some fields are badly formatted *and* this is not critical, I don't put a \@NotNull on these fields => error will be filtered

Comment: Yes, you are right, your approach is better.
I'm interested how you make it work for a primitive value, because i want my domain model to have a **private int age**, instead of **private Integer age**.
I managed to solve this by using **new StdDeserializer.IntegerDeserializer(int.class, 0),** and replacing the **return null** from deserialize method with **return delegate.getNullValue();**. If you think this is the correct solution, please update your code to include this as well, if you have another approach, please share.

Comment: I'm wondering if it is a good idea to consider raw types in that case. Because it sounds weird to me to use some values to represent an "illegal" value (in your case, the value seems to be 0). I'd rather use a less used value such as Integer.MAX_VALUE, but even in that case, I find this behaviour a bit too arbitrary (this is a personnal POV)

Comment: A simple check of `if(ex.getCause() instanceof JsonMappingException)` (and appropriate logic to either re-throw or delegate handling of other exception types if not) eliminates any possibility of getting a `ClassCastException`.  Otherwise, useful answer

Answer (score 2):

I have written a simple error handler which will give you some kind of error which you can return to user with bad request as status code. Use @JsonProperty required = true to get error related to missing properties. Jackson version 2.9.8.

```
public class JacksonExceptionHandler {

    public String getErrorMessage(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
        String message = null;
        boolean handled = false;
        Throwable cause = e.getRootCause();

        if (cause instanceof UnrecognizedPropertyException) {
            UnrecognizedPropertyException exception = (UnrecognizedPropertyException) cause;
            message = handleUnrecognizedPropertyException(exception);
            handled = true;
        }
        if (cause instanceof InvalidFormatException) {
            InvalidFormatException exception = (InvalidFormatException) cause;
            message = handleInvalidFormatException(exception);
            handled = true;
        }
        if (cause instanceof MismatchedInputException) {
            if (!handled) {
                MismatchedInputException exception = (MismatchedInputException) cause;
                message = handleMisMatchInputException(exception);
            }
        }
        if (cause instanceof JsonParseException) {
            message = "Malformed json";
        }
        return message;
    }

    private String handleInvalidFormatException(InvalidFormatException exception) {
        String reference = null;
        if (!exception.getPath().isEmpty()) {
            String path = extractPropertyReference(exception.getPath());
            reference = removeLastCharacter(path);
        }
        Object value = exception.getValue();
        return "Invalid value '" + value + "' for property : " + reference;
    }

    private String handleUnrecognizedPropertyException(UnrecognizedPropertyException exception) {
        String reference = null;
        if (!exception.getPath().isEmpty()) {
            String path = extractPropertyReference(exception.getPath());
            reference = removeLastCharacter(path);
        }
        return "Unknown property : '" + reference + "'";
    }

    private String handleMisMatchInputException(MismatchedInputException exception) {
        String reference = null;
        if (!exception.getPath().isEmpty()) {
            reference = extractPropertyReference(exception.getPath());
        }
        String property = StringUtils.substringBetween(exception.getLocalizedMessage(), "'", "'");
        // if property missing inside nested object
        if (reference != null && property!=null) {
            return "Missing property : '" + reference + property + "'";
        }
        // if invalid value given to array
        if(property==null){
            return "Invalid values at : '"+ reference +"'";
        }
        // if property missing at root level
        else return "Missing property : '" + property + "'";
    }

    // extract nested object name for which property is missing
    private String extractPropertyReference(List<JsonMappingException.Reference> path) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        path.forEach(reference -> {
                    if(reference.getFieldName() != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(reference.getFieldName()).append(".");
                        // if field is null means it is array
                    } else stringBuilder.append("[].");
                }
                );
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    // remove '.' at the end of property path reference
    private String removeLastCharacter(String string) {
        return string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
    }
}
```

and call this class object in global advice like this

```
@Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        String message = new JacksonExceptionHandler().generator.getErrorMessage(ex);
        if(message == null){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Malformed json");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(message);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple Mapper:

```java
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JSONProcessingErrorMapper
        implements ExceptionMapper<InvalidFormatException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(InvalidFormatException ex) { 
        return Response.status(400)
                 .entity(new ClientError("[User friendly message]"))
                 .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                 .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[DeserializationProblemHandler](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.14.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/DeserializationProblemHandler.html) now has a lot more methods, such as `handleUnexpectedToken` and   `handleWeird*Value`. It should be able to handle anything one needs.

Subclass it, override methods you need, then add it to your `ObjectMapper` with `addHandler(DeserializationProblemHandler h)`.