# Aggregate all the errors while mapping json to java object using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to map a JSON string to a Java Object using Jackson ObjectMapper. If there is a mapping error, Jackson throws an exception when it first encounters the error. Is there a way to ask the ObjectMapper to map all the field while collecting the errors, and return all possible errors together?

The Java class

```
public class Test {
    public int field1;
    public int field2;
    public Test() {}
}
```

Mapper Code snippet

```
String json = "{\"field1\":field, \"field2\":anotherField}";
Test test = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Test.class);
```

The above code fails when it tries to parse 'field' to int, and doesn't check for remaining fields. However, the in the code, neither field1 nor field2 can be parsed. Is there a way to get all the potential errors at once, so I don't have to fix 1 error at a time?

Comment: Is your problem just to handle problems of int parsing or you want to solve *any* jackson parsing problems?

Comment: @AlexR I want to handle any mapping problem, including parsing and missing fields (i.e., if the json string had a key 'field3' which doesn't map to any field in the Java object)

Answer (score 1):

Well, IMHO the problem does not have one simple solution.
However particular solutions can be found.

If you want to ignore missing fields just use annotation

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

Supporting unparsable data is more complicated. Please take a look on correct answer from this discussion [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080904/jackson-deserialization-error-handling).

It however will not help if your JSON is syntactically wrong, for example if coma or colon are missing.

Comment: I don't want to ignore the missing field. I don't want the mapper to fail at the _first_ instance of error. If there are multiple missing fields, I want that the error shows _all_ the missing fields, and not just the first one.

Comment: So, use solution similar to referenced for unparsable types.

Comment: Thanks, but even using a similar strategy, the best I could do was ignore the error and return null for the value.
I could think of storing the exceptions, but I want to keep the mapper thread-safe.