# Get better parsing error with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I'm parsing a rather big file plenty of lines and columns. Now, sometimes I get new data as well, which sometimes can be faulty as well. Things that a `double` is suddenly a `String` or any other change of type. When running it this kind of parsing error, Jackson is reporting the column, value and the line and then basically stops the parsing process.

I think it is a `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException`.

What I would like to achieve, is that is

1. Report the whole row, as for example column 27 is faulty but to easily track it down I would need column columns 1, as it carries the identifier of the dataset.
2. Be able to skip failed columns and continue the parsing process ignoring/just-reporting the faulty column.

I couldn't find any documentation for that. If there is any, I would appreciate a pointer.

**EDIT**: I think it is a `InvalidFormatException`

Comment: JSON doesn't have the idea of columns, so not clear what you mean "faulty/failed". If a quote or bracket is wrong, you can't just skip it

Comment: JSON doesn't, but Jackson can parse tab files. I would need that information.

Comment: When I say "faulty/failed", I mean that in my Java model I have a:
`public int zipCode`
And now there is one faulty row, which I'm parsing where `zipCode` is a string.

Comment: I don't think the Jackson CSV parser returns a `JsonParseException`

Comment: Well, that's a bad model that you're assuming zip codes are numeric... Look up the values for Canadian zip codes. Also leading zeros matter

Comment: The zip is an example. Can be age as well. The point is that the field has been wrongly annotated in the file where I'm reading from.

Comment: In fact it is a InvalidFormatException.

Comment: If the file is wrong, then it shouldn't really be Jackson's responsibility to clean it up. It assumes that the file is defined by a single schema. I don't know the internals of the library, but I also doubt there's no "extra logging" that can be enabled to get the information your asking for, so I would suggest parsing the data yourself using Apache Commons CSV, for example

Comment: I agree with the cleaning up, but I'd like to have a more meaning full error.

Comment: Can you put some sample code, input data set, etc

Comment: @cricket_007 this question seems to be about the error *message*, not about fixing the error.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that you have a *syntactically valid* JSON document, you can create a deserializer to ignore parsing errors due to type mismatch or type conversion. The implementation doesn't need to handle the deserilization itself, it can delegate to an existing deserializer from the Jackson API. This approach was first described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9097834/1426227).

For error reporting you can catch a [`JsonProcessingException`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException.html), check for a particular subtype and then get some details from the exception API. Depending on your needs, the [`JsonParser`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html) and [`DeserializationContext`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext.html) APIs can give you additional details for your logs.

See below what the custom deserializer could be like:

```java
public class NonBlockingDeserializer<T> extends JsonDeserializer<T> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(NonBlockingDeserializer.class.getName());

    private StdDeserializer<T> delegate;

    public NonBlockingDeserializer(StdDeserializer<T> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        try {

            // Delegate the deserialization
            return delegate.deserialize(jp, ctxt);

        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {

            // Log the exception
            logException(e);

            // Return default null value
            return delegate.getNullValue(ctxt);
        }
    }

    private void logException(JsonProcessingException e) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(e.getOriginalMessage() + System.lineSeparator());

        builder.append(String.format("Source: %s \n", e.getLocation().getSourceRef()));
        builder.append(String.format("Line: %s \n", e.getLocation().getLineNr()));
        builder.append(String.format("Column: %s \n", e.getLocation().getColumnNr()));

        if (e instanceof InvalidFormatException) {

            InvalidFormatException e1 = (InvalidFormatException) e;
            builder.append(String.format("Value: %s \n", e1.getValue()));
            builder.append(String.format("Value type: %s \n", e1.getValue().getClass().getTypeName()));
            builder.append(String.format("Target type: %s \n", e1.getTargetType().getTypeName()));

        } else if (e instanceof UnrecognizedPropertyException) {

            UnrecognizedPropertyException e1 = (UnrecognizedPropertyException) e;
            builder.append(String.format("Property name: %s \n", e1.getPropertyName()));
            builder.append(String.format("Known properties: %s \n", e1.getKnownPropertyIds()));

        }

        LOGGER.warning(builder.toString());
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows, adding the deserializers for the types you want to ignore the errors:

```java
// Create module for custom deserializers
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("customDeserializers", Version.unknownVersion());

// Add deserializers for primitive types
module.addDeserializer(Double.TYPE,   new NonBlockingDeserializer<Double>(
                                      new NumberDeserializers.DoubleDeserializer(Double.TYPE, 0.d)));
module.addDeserializer(Integer.TYPE,  new NonBlockingDeserializer<Integer>(
                                      new NumberDeserializers.IntegerDeserializer(Integer.TYPE, 0)));

// Add deserializers for wrapper classes
module.addDeserializer(Double.class,  new NonBlockingDeserializer<Double>(
                                      new NumberDeserializers.DoubleDeserializer(Double.class, null)));
module.addDeserializer(Integer.class, new NonBlockingDeserializer<Integer>(
                                      new NumberDeserializers.IntegerDeserializer(Integer.class, null)));

// Create ObjectMapper and register module
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(module);

// Perform the deserialization as usual
Foo foo = mapper.readValue(json, Foo.class);
```

The parsing errors will be logged like:

```
Mar 11, 2018 10:45:33 AM org.example.playground.NonBlockingDeserializer logException
WARNING: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from String "18a": not a valid Integer value
Source: {"name": "Joe", "age": "18a"} 
Line: 1 
Column: 24 
Value: 18a 
Value type: java.lang.String 
Target type: java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: I don't think this is the answer the OP is looking for. The issue is not about what caused the exception, rather how to continue even with exception

Comment: This looks better. @tschaka1904, can you check if your requirement is met with the updated answer?

Comment: Looks good! I think there now just in issue still on my side! For the `Source`, `org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExec‌​utor$UnCloseableInpu‌​Stream`, which I seem not to be able to convert into a string.. Which is annoying, but all the rest works!