# How to handle jackson deserialization error for all kinds of data mismatch in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, exception, jackson

I know there is some similar questions here about how to parse ENUM, how to parse customize JSON structure. But here my question is how to just give a better message when the user submit some JSON with is not as expected.

This is the code:

```
@PutMapping
public ResponseEntity updateLimitations(@PathVariable("userId") String userId,
                                        @RequestBody LimitationParams params) {
  Limitations limitations = user.getLimitations();
  params.getDatasets().forEach(limitations::updateDatasetLimitation);
  params.getResources().forEach(limitations::updateResourceLimitation);
  userRepository.save(user);
  return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
}
```

And the request body I expected is like this:

```
{
  "datasets": {"public": 10},
  "resources": {"cpu": 2}
}
```

But when they submit something like this:

```
{
  "datasets": {"public": "str"}, // <--- a string is given
  "resources": {"cpu": 2}
}
```

The response will show something like this in logs:

```
400 JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from String "invalid": not a valid Integer value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from String "invalid": not a valid Integer value
```

at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 23] (through reference chain: com.openbayes.api.users.LimitationParams["datasets"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["public"])

But what I want is a more human readable message.

I tried to use `ExceptionHandler` for `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException` but it doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080904/jackson-deserialization-error-handling might help you

Answer (score 1):

You can write a controller advice to catch exceptions and return corresponding error response.

Here is an example of controller advice in spring boot :

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidFormatException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> invalidFormatException(final InvalidFormatException e) {
        return error(e, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    private ResponseEntity <ErrorResponse> error(final Exception exception, final HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        final String message = Optional.ofNullable(exception.getMessage()).orElse(exception.getClass().getSimpleName());
        return new ResponseEntity(new ErrorResponse(message), httpStatus);
    }
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ErrorResponse {
    private String errorMessage;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I can not get a json response, it seems that the InvalidFormatException is not being handled.

Comment: Did you get an error? Does it reach the code on controller advice when debug the application?

Comment: No, it didn't reach the code in controller advice, the break point was not triggered.

Comment: I just asking for clarify, is there any try catch clause which may be caught the expception?

Comment: I didn't find where caught the exception...But I think be may you are right.

Answer (score 1):

The real exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException.
Intercept this and it will work.

```
public ResponseEntity<String> handle(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("your own message" + e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following error handling method is worked for me.

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    public ResponseEntity handleAllOtherErrors(HttpMessageNotReadableException formatException) {
        String error = formatException.getMessage().toString();
return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

Comment: Good approach, one note though: This will work as long as you are not extending `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` in your handler class. Because the parent class already takes care of this exception in its `handlerExceptionResolver` method, and you'll end up with bean creation error.
Error is: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException]`