# Handle jackson excpetions with wrong formatted json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Jackson SubType in the following code :

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "animal_type", visible = true,defaultImpl = Void.class)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Bird.class, name = "bird"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Lion.class, name = "lion"),
})
public class Animal implements Serializable {
   private String animal_type;
   private int age;
   private String name;
```

When I pass an invalid json I'm getting exception in my console because of wrong animal_type or wrong keys that I'm passing. My goal is to return null instead of throwing those exceptions..

**A few examples :**

1.`{"animal_type":null,"age":4,"name":"king"}`

```
[main] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Could not resolve type id 'null'
```

2.`{"animal_type":"lion","age":4,"name":"king","invalid_key":50}`

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "invalid_key"
```

The mapping is happening in 2 parts in my code :

In one of my tests :

```
Animal a = mapper.readValue(animal,Animal.class);
```

And the second place is in my controller when I get an Animal :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "animal", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<Animal> processAnimals(@RequestBody List<Animal> animals) {
```

Instead of throwing exception I would like the mapper to just return null as it will indicate that it failed mapping the json to an object.

I tried to add `defaultImpl = Void.class` but it didn't help. Is there any way to do it without writing a new deserializer?

Comment: can you post the exceptions

Comment: sure, I'll update in a sec

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/52196438/9050514