# How to ignore a list entry causing a deserialization error in Jackson?

Tags: java, error-handling, jackson, json-deserialization, jackson-databind

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON structure with Jackson and I'm working with a DTO that looks like this:

```java
public class RootLevelDTO {
   
    private List<ComplexEntry> complexEntries;
    // ... other fields, not relevant

}
```

Now, the `ComplexEntry` can have sub-types, those have properties of enum types etc. A lot can go wrong here if the other side of the communication updates their API and e.g. adds another sub type or adds an enum literal.

What I would like to do is to tell Jackson:

- if you encounter any databinding error during deserialization of the `complexEntries` field...
- ... do **not** throw an exception, but instead **ignore** this entry and continue with the next.

What I tried so far is to use a delegating deserializer for `ComplexEntry`:

```java
public class ComplexEntryDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<ComplexEntry> {

    private StdDeserializer<ComplexEntry> delegate;

    public ComplexEntryDeserializer(StdDeserializer<ComplexEntry> delegate){
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public ComplexEntry deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt){
        try {
            return this.delegate.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        }catch(Exception e){
            // the list entry failed to deserialize, but we have to return *something* here
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    // ... other mandatory methods, not relevant here
}
```

This solution has the problem that it will introduce `null` values to the `complexEntries` list, which I then have to explicitly get rid of with a `Converter`.

Is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: This reads like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454), i.e. you chose the wrong solution and are going the wrong way. Sounds like you really need to tell Jackson: *"if you encounter any unknown properties, just capture them in a generic `Map<String, Object>`"*. Parsing will then never fail, and all (unknown) data is parsed correctly. See e.g. [3.3. @JsonAnySetter](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#3-jsonanysetter) in the Baeldung article "Jackson Annotation Examples".

Comment: @Andreas generic objects won't work. The fields in my DTOs have clearly defined Java types (objects, enums, lists of those). Jackson cannot attempt to assign any value to an enum field, except for a literal of that enum - the JVM will not allow that, and rightfully so.

Comment: Please take a step back and think about the problem itself: if the api is updated would you really want to (silently) ignore any unknown types or properties? Wouldn't those be relevant at some point? Also, who is the owner of the api? Is it you or the other side?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, that's exactly what I intend to do. It's not about unknown properties of certain objects; Jackson can ignore those easily enough through settings. I'm dealing with unknown subtypes, and unknown literals of enums. I don't want Jackson to crash when that happens, it should just ignore the list entry.

Comment: Well, in case you really need to do this you could try and provide a decorated, final list in your dto that ignores nulls. If I remember correctly, only providing a getter for such a list should make Jackson use that instance to add deserialized elements.

Comment: If your code needs to handle future data (gracefully), then it needs to be designed to do so. E.g. if the API specifies an ENUM type, i.e. a fixed list of string values, but future versions may contain new values, then it is not really an ENUM type, but just a string, with a (current) list of known values. Make your DTO use a string field, then write code to provide good well-explained error handling when an unknown value is encountered, like when you use a `switch` statement and put error handling in the `default` clause. Error can explain which field has which unknown value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of tinkering I've ended up with the following solution. It doesn't require any additional jackson modules or other magic, only a single (specific) deserializer.

DTO:

```java
public class RootLevelDTO {

    // use a custom deserializer for the list
    @JsonDeserialize(using = ListOfComplexEntryDeserializer.class)
    private List<ComplexEntry> complexEntries;

}
```

Deserializer:

```java
public class ListOfComplexEntryDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<ComplexEntry>> {

    @Override
    public List<ComplexEntry> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) {
        List<ComplexEntry> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        while(p.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY){
            try {
                // delegate the deserialization of the individual list entries to the standard deserializers
                resultList.add(ctxt.readValue(p, ComplexEntry.class))
            }catch(Exception e){
                // log that the entry wasn't deserialized properly
                System.out.println("ComplexEntry could not be read and will be ignored.");
            }
        }
        return resultList;
    }

}
```

Big disclaimer: While the code above **works**, it's not something you should go for by design. I'm really with my back to the wall here and have no other choice (due to external factors beyond my control), and for that case it works.

Comment: There's a similar solution posted here by one of the Jackson guys: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9097834/5209935 - the main difference is they made it generic.